# connect as another user to oracle 12 c

Tags: oracle12c

I have to connect as "dba1" to my pluggable database.I issued the following:

```
con dba1/oracle@FIRST as sysdba;
```

(FIRST is my pluggable db)
But it gives a warning "Database not connected to Oracle"

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: search for the exact error text in a search engine - you have not provided enough information for us to answer this question.

Comment: ORA 12154 "TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier supplied"

Comment: Is FIRST the SID and/or service name of the pluggable DB? Do you have an alias defined with that name in your client `tnsnames.ora` file? (The error suggests you do not). If you know the remote host, port and service name you can use easy connect syntax instead of a TNS alias.

Comment: yes I do know the remote host and port.Can you suggest a generic statement using easyconnect please? thanks !

Comment: The syntax is `con dba1/oracle@//hostname:port/service_name`. The [docs cover various ways to connect](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/naming.htm); that starts with easy connect, but also shows [local naming](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/naming.htm#NETAG256), which is the syntax you were attempting in the question.